# Folder keeps popping up in my public_html directory and overriding Wordpress page structure

Tags: directory

My client requires that a page have be located at `/connect`, but when accessing the built page, only a parent directory tree is displayed.

After a lot of looking around, I found that the problem was caused by the directory `public_html/connect`; a directory completely empty other than a `.well-known` folder. After deleting the folder, the page worked perfectly, but a few days later, the folder came back and broke the page again.

Any advice on where could I start looking to find the culprit for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've usually seen a  `.well-known` folder associated with site ownership validation for SSL certificates.

You may find the following [link from Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/795467/for-what-is-the-well-known-folder) may assist in further understanding.

Maybe you can convince the Client to have a different folder name?

Comment: It was made by Let's Encrypt, so that's the string for me to pull on

Answer (score 1):

It may be caused by one of your plugins; I'd check there first. Some plugins like to create folders for their own use.

I'd also check your htaccess file for the standard WP redirects (and no others that are not expected).

Finally, add this line to your htaccess in the domain root to prevent directory listings:

```
Options -Indexes
```